# Bacula on 22.04

Tags: backup, 22.04

After my upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 I find that there is no bacula-fd binary and also no package. The other two components director and sd are present and also have packages, but no fd. Bacula worked fine on 21.10 before the upgrade.

Does anyone have Bacula working on 22.04?

Answer (score 2):

Since I only need to install bacula-fd on my Ubuntu servers, I have opted for using the packages from Focal Fossa (20.04 LTS) which have bacula-fd 9.4.2 instead of 9.6.7 on Impish (21.10 non-LTS)

Download the packages from the downloadable files section on the top right:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/libssl1.1/1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/bacula-common/9.4.2-2ubuntu5
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/bacula-fd/9.4.2-2ubuntu5

To install:

```
dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
dpkg -i bacula-common_9.4.2-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb
dpkg -i bacula-fd_9.4.2-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Note: that I have not used any SSL/TLS features of bacula-fd on this install:

Comment: thanks that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you search for bacula on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ you will find only the bacula-doc package for jammy (22.04).

On https://packages.debian.org/ you will find all bacula packages for the newest debian.

The ubuntu 21.10 has also all bacula-packages in the universe repository.

I don't know what happened between ubuntu 21.10 and 22.04...

Answer (score 1):

According to alex.murray@canonical.com : It seems it (bacula-fd) was removed during the jammy development cycle as it failed to build from source.

As for my experience:

The other two packages (bacula-sd and bacula-director) are in the distribution. bacula-fd from 21.10 installs and works fine on 22.04. I also built from src and didn't see the error that Alex referred to in the build. However, I never installed it since I already had the one from 21.10 working.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bacula/+bug/1973322

Answer (score 0):

Install bacula-director and bacula-sd on a non ubuntu 22.04 system. To backup your 22.04 use a self compiled, static bacula-fd.

1. Download sources from bacula website
2. unpack them
3. configure as static without openssl with    `./configure --enable-static-fd --enable-client-only --disable-libtool --without-openssl`
4. Ignore any build fails. You're finished when ./src/filed/bacula-fd is existing, then strip it with   `strip ./src/filed/bacula-fd`
5. copy bacula-fd and bacula-fd.conf to your ubuntu 22.04 system and have fun.
6. BEWARE OF UNENCRYPTED BACKUP STREAMS !!!!

Openssl for a backup stream isn't a good choice if you're not an expert in encryption. The overall speed without changing anything is horrible slow, not suitable for a backup.
Use a wireguard vpn instead and let your backup stream travel unencrypted within your vpn. Wireguard is easy to install and has a safe and fast encryption algorithm per default. This is the best mixture of performance and security you can have.

Don't compile bacula-fd as static if you not agree with backup within your vpn.You have been warned if you do so :) I'm not responsible for any stolen data or any other bad thing that may happen.

I hope we will have bacula-* back in ubuntu 22.04 repository. For me it's a criteria to change linux distribution to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Binary packages for the latest versions are provided directly from bacula.org.

https://www.bacula.org/bacula-binary-package-download/

Registration is required in order to get a link to the packages.